# Simple encryption and decryption of a txt document

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, text-files

I'm making an application that writes a small txt file containing 3 strings then loads them back into the application in a list widget.

This all works fine, but now I want to make it so that the txt file is not in plain text. I don't need any complicated cipher or anything that needs a key to encrypt and decrypt. I just simply want to be able to encrypt it on saving (saves a document that isn't in plain text) and decrypt it before it loads it back into the lost widget.

Below is my code for writing to and reading from the txt file. I'd just like to rework this so it's not plain text nothing else and I don't care that its not secure just not plain text

```
QFile m_file("mytext.txt");
m_file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Append);
QTextStream m_stream(&m_file);
m_stream << ui->txt_1->text() + "    " + ui->txt_2->text() + "    " + ui->txt_3->text()                         <<;
m_file.close(); 




QFile n_file("mytext.txt");
n_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QTextStream n_stream(&n_file);
int i=0;
while (!n_stream.atEnd())
{
    ui->listWidget->addItem(n_stream.readLine());
    i++;
}
```

Comment: If all you want is the bare bare minimum, you can always just XOR all of the bytes when saving, and then XOR them again when loading the data back in.  That would stop people who think opening a file in Notepad is "hacking", although of course anyone who knows anything about cryptography would figure it out quickly enough.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner XOR the bytes with what?

Comment: thanks for the comment i have seen this on different forums but i dont know how to do this anyway anyone could produce some sample code to just xor a txt doument ?

Comment: @erickson: If you XOR them with themselves you have a nice variable cipher that's self-securing.

Comment: @erickson: Some arbitrary number, not zero. Probably best if it's less  than 32, so that all printable characters stay printable.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you XOR all the lines, then you need to know what they were to decrypt. If you already know what the strings were, why store them?

Answer (score 1):

I know you do not want to hear this, but encryption is something you do not want to do yourself. The easiest really is to use a good library for this, such as [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/).

If you really feel the need to do something yourself, the [Vignère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) is a very simple algorithm to code, but also very simple to break.

Comment: @user What's the point? If you don't want security then leave it as it is. Why do you want to pretend to secure it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

```
void cyptStr(char *str){
    if(!str){
        return;
    }
    char *end = str + (strlen(str) - 1);
    for(;str < end;str++){
        if (*str != ' ')
            *str ^= 1;
    }
}
void ucyptStr(char *str){
    if(!str){
        return;
    }
    char *end = str + (strlen(str) - 1);
    for(;str < end;str++){
        if (*str != ' ')
            *str ^= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's going to remove any `!` characters from the string. You'd be better off actually XOR'ing - change both loop bodies to `*str ^= 1` (or some other value).

Comment: This isn't XORing. It looks like ROT1.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I'm partial to XOR 0x42, myself

Comment: That is better, but it will still just rotate characters up or down by one. Use a different constant, one that will preserve the printability of the characters but be a little harder to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your question and comments, you do not want to any external library to achieve this simple task.
Here are the alternatives:

1- Use **own encrypt/decrypt function**. Then, simply, call encrypt function when writing, call decrypt function when reading.
Here are usable code for this purpose. (Same function used for enc/dec, little hacky)

```
string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt) {
    char key[3] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Any chars will work, in an array of any size
    string output = toEncrypt;

    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];

    return output;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string encrypted = encryptDecrypt("kylewbanks.com");
    cout << "Encrypted:" << encrypted << "\n";

    string decrypted = encryptDecrypt(encrypted);
    cout << "Decrypted:" << decrypted << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

2- To absolute security and more standard code use a cipher algorithm. Best way to using a cipher algorithm is selecting a state-of-the-art crypto library like [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) or [Qt Cryptographic Architecture (QCA)](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/).

Choice is yours.